# the same html file from github doesn't work the same way under different folders

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I cloned a project from github by using Git Desktop app on Windows. I have the files in my GitHub folder locally. When I run the index.html it looks fine as expected.

The problem is when I copy and paste the same folder to somewhere else in my local and open the index.html in my browser, it doesn't work properly. Margins and paddings are shifted. Most of the images aren't seen. Etc...

The same issue also happens when I don't clone but download the same project.

Any ideas why it happens?

Comment: What does "run the index.html" mean? Do you see anything interesting in your browser's console?

Comment: Fixed it, I meant "open it in the browser".  What I wonder is "cloning a project" or "downloading a project" make any difference?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. What about the second part of my question? Do you see anything interesting in your browser's console? Are you opening the file in the same way both times, e.g. fia File → Open?